# Make links clickable with regex

Tags: php, regex

Is there a regex out there that can find a string that contains a word that starts with either http:// or www and wrap it with `<a>$1</a>`?

Been googling but I can't seem to find a ultimate one.

Another question, Could you somehow make it ignore it if its inside a `<img>` tag ?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    $text = trim($text);
    while ($text != stripslashes($text)) { $text = stripslashes($text); }    
    $text = strip_tags($text,"<b><i><u>");
    $text = preg_replace("/(?<!http:\/\/)www\./","http://www.",$text);
    $text = preg_replace( "/((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>",$text);
```

Comment: a snippet from a function I use often; also contains (not shown) code to replace email with links, optionally obfuscated

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with this one — finding the beginning is fairly easy (most of the time); finding the end? Good luck:

- `http://example.com/bob.jones.4.`
- `http://example.com/bob.jones.4?`
- `http://example.com/bob.jones.4!`
- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242733/make-links(oh-noes)`
- `http://example.com/bob.'magic'.jones*2!`
- `http://example.com/~(*)!`

Those are valid URLs. See RFC2396. But sometimes you want the trailing punctuation, sometimes you don't.

*/me wonders what he can use a url with `(*')!` in it for, now that he knows its permitted by RFC2396.*

Comment: What's the problem using all characters in a string? If it before escape them with functions like htmlentites all is goo, isnt it?

Comment: @kwichz: The problem is that in a plan text string, its easy to find http://, but its difficult to find the *end* of the URL, due to all the characters that are allowed in a URL. For example: `He said to 'Try searching at http://www.google.com/.'` Both period and single-quote are valid characters in a URL, so its difficult for a program to see where that URL ends.

Comment: I fail to see the problem. Just match until you find the first space and it will work in most cases.

Comment: @MaciejSwic `Well, that fails on the common convention of wrapping URLs in punctuation (e.g., <http://www.example.com>). Or on URLs at ends of sentences, like http://www.example.com/page1.html. You can get a 90% solution, as you say, but should be aware of how it'll fail.` (Comment wrapped in \` to prevent SO from messing it up...)